# Resharper 6 live templates for CQRS dev

Tags: resharper, cqrs, boilerplate, resharper-6.0, scrap-your-boilerplate

There's been some chatter on the ddd-cqrs list about people using Resharper live templates to help take care of the boilerplate code that you get when doing CQRS dev.

Is this the best way to overcome the boilerplate madness and does anyone have any they'd like to share with the community?

Comment: I think this question belongs in a different forum.

Comment: i see other questions about live templates on so?

Comment: The question is pretty open-ended.

Comment: made it a bit more specific. it would be beneficial to the community to have this out there :)

Comment: I've seen T4 templates used for CQRS boiler plate code and I would strongly recommend against doing so.  It creates large sections of code people aren't comfortable changing because the next time the template runs their work goes away.  I'd think Live Templates would be MUCH preferable.

Answer (score 0):

CQRS at its most basic is about keeping your queries and your commands separated.  A concept this simple shouldn't actually require any boiler plate code (hence the backlash against frameworks on the ddd-cqrs list).

That said, CQRS with Event Sourcing DOES have quite a bit of boiler plate code you need generated.  And like all code that is repetitive in nature using something like ReSharper live templates sounds like a great idea.

The problem will be if usage of the templates stops people from improving things or changing how things are done.  The templates should be considered as living things that need to be maintained and cared for so that you're not afraid of improving your implementation.